# Spring batch running in a docker container to Write file out of the docker container - directly to the SFTP remote server

Tags: docker, spring-batch, sftp

My spring batch job running in a docker container reads data from DB and creates a flatfile. For now the file is created inside the container but when data is big, i want to create the flatfile in the remote SFTP location.
What would be the best way to implement this without creating a physical file inside a container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the `org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient` class, `storeFileStream` method to obtain an `OutputStream`, then write directly to that `OutputStream` when reading rows from your database.

See https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#storeFileStream-java.lang.String-

Comment: This works fine, although the performance of the job went down a little but i'd take it.